# Does System.Event get executed in the Main thread?

Tags: windows, event-handling

I want to know that when we implement any System.Event in the program, doest that event and the event handler run in Main thread of the program or they get executed in the seperate thread ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The event gets executed on the thread that raises the event.

Comment: can you tell me how can I check that